# Glitchy collision resolution between mouse-controlled player and obstacle squares

Tags: javascript, canvas

I am trying to make a game with collision detection and resolution. For some reason, when I move the player to the right of the 'enemy blocks', the player moves to the left of the 'enemy'. How can I solve this problem? I have been working on this for hours and cannot find any solution. I am not sure if it is a small problem or if I have to change the whole enemy object.

```js
//declare variables
var body = document.getElementById("body");
var canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
var iwidth = window.innerWidth;
var iheight = window.innerHeight;
//variable for drawing
var draw = canvas.getContext("2d");
//variables for character paramaters
var playerwidth = 20;
var playerheight = 20;
var playerx = iwidth / 2 - playerwidth / 2;
var playery = iheight / 2 - playerheight / 2;
var playerspeed = 20;
//mouse co-ordinates
var mousex;
var mousey;
//enemy's parameters
var enemyxpositions = [43, 94, 200];
var enemyypositions = [41, 120, 83];
var enemywidths = [12, 43, 45];
var enemyheights = [43, 11, 87];
var i = 0;
var collision = false;
///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
///////         separating variables and rest of the code                   ///////              
///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

//puts canvas in top right corner
body.style.margin = "0";


//changes the canvas's style namely color, margin, width and height
canvas.style.backgroundColor = "black";
canvas.style.margin = "0";
canvas.width = iwidth;
canvas.height = iheight;

//the function that the player is drawn in
function drawplayer() { 

 //allows animation
 requestAnimationFrame(drawplayer);

 //clears the canvas every time the function runs so that the image doesn't leave a mark
 draw.clearRect(0, 0, iwidth, iheight);


 //drawing the player
 draw.fillStyle = "#ffff00";
 draw.fillRect(playerx, playery, playerwidth, playerheight);
 draw.fill();


 //checking where the mouse is and letting the player follow it
 if (mousex > playerx + playerwidth / 2) {
  playerx += (mousex - playerx + playerwidth) / playerspeed;
 }
 if (mousex < playerx + playerwidth / 2) {
  playerx -= (playerx - mousex + playerwidth) / playerspeed;
 }
 if (mousey > playery + playerheight / 2) {
  playery += (mousey - playery + playerheight) / playerspeed;
 }
 if (mousey < playery + playerheight / 2) {
  playery -= (playery - mousey + playerheight) / playerspeed;
 }


 //the obstacles' object
 function Enemy(enemyx, enemyy, enemywidth, enemyheight) {
  this.enemyx = enemyx;
  this.enemyy = enemyy;
  this.enemywidth = enemywidth;
  this.enemyheight = enemyheight;
  this.enemies = function() {
   draw.fillStyle = "#0000ff";
   draw.fillRect(enemyx, enemyy, enemywidth, enemyheight);
   draw.fill();
  }
 

  //collision detection
  if (mousex + playerwidth / 2 > this.enemyx && 
   mousex - playerwidth / 2 < this.enemyx + this.enemywidth &&
   mousey + playerheight / 2 > this.enemyy &&
   mousey - playerheight / 2 < this.enemyy + this.enemyheight) {
    collision = true;
  }
  else {
   collision = false;
  }

  //collision implementation
  //left collision
  if (collision == true && mousex + playerwidth / 2 > this.enemyx) {
   playerx = this.enemyx - playerwidth;
  }
  //right collision
  else if (collision == true && mousex - playerwidth / 2 < this.enemyx + this.enemywidth) {
   playerx = this.enemyx + this.enemywidth + 50;
  }
  



 }

  //draws all the obstacles
  for (i = 0; i < enemyxpositions.length; i++) {
   new Enemy( enemyxpositions[i],
      enemyypositions[i],
      enemywidths[i],
      enemyheights[i]).enemies();
  }


}
drawplayer();


//gets the mouse co-ordinates
window.onmousemove = function mousepos(event) {
 mousex = event.clientX;
 mousey = event.clientY;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
 <meta charset="UTF-8">
 <title>DUNGE</title>
 <style>
  ::-webkit-scrollbar {
   display: none;
  }
  canvas {
   display: block;
  }
  #obstacles {
   opacity: 1;
   margin-top: -100vh;
  }
 </style>
</head>
<body id="body">
 
 <canvas id="canvas"></canvas>
 <script src="script.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Simplify your code. Create a [mcve] without CSS (it doesn't contribute to the problem), and with only a single obstacle, and single "player", already positioned in a colliding orientation, and then run your function, once. Which code path does the code take? Remove everything else, it does not contribute to your problem, and now you're laser-focussing on where the problem might be: at each part inside the function, how do the values differ from what you expected? Dev tools "debug" can be very helpful here, to step through what your function does one line at a line, while watching var values.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Collision resolution is a pretty tricky domain and there are a many approaches you can take. For the purposes of squares with mouse control as in your case, a naive approach might be as follows:

If a collision is detected between a player and an immobile obstacle (enemy, wall, whatever), we can resolve the collision by gradually "undoing" the player's motion until it's no longer colliding with the obstacle.

For example, if on the current frame, the player is moving with a `y` velocity of 5 and an `x` velocity of 2 and we detect a collision, then we can avoid the collision by undoing the move. However, this would create an unrealistic air gap between the obstacle and the player that can result in a bouncing effect. Instead, we can slowly move the obstacle's `x` and `y` positions by a small value like -0.5 until no collision is detected. However, undoing the move on both axes might be incorrect if only one axis experienced a collision.

Here's an initial attempt at separating the x and y axes into distinct steps:

```js
const canvas = document.createElement("canvas");
canvas.width = 300;
canvas.height = 180;
document.body.appendChild(canvas);
const ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
const mouse = {x: 0, y: 0};
const enemy = {x: 130, y: 70, width: 40, height: 40};
const player = {
  x: 0, y: 0, width: 20, height: 20, vx: 0, vy: 0, 
  velocityDamp: 0.06, collisionDamp: 0.3
};

const collides = (a, b) => 
  a.x + a.width >= b.x && a.x <= b.x + b.width &&
  a.y + a.height >= b.y && a.y <= b.y + b.height
;

(function render() {
  player.vx = (mouse.x - player.x) * player.velocityDamp;
  player.vy = (mouse.y - player.y) * player.velocityDamp;
  player.x += player.vx;
  player.y += player.vy;

  while (collides(player, enemy)) {
    player.y -= Math.sign(player.vy) * player.collisionDamp;
  }

  while (collides(player, enemy)) {
    player.x -= Math.sign(player.vx) * player.collisionDamp;
  }

  ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
  ctx.fillStyle = "blue";
  ctx.fillRect(enemy.x, enemy.y, enemy.width, enemy.height);
  ctx.fillStyle = "yellow";
  ctx.fillRect(player.x, player.y, player.width, player.height);  
  requestAnimationFrame(render);
})();

onmousemove = e => {
  mouse.x = e.clientX;
  mouse.y = e.clientY;
};
```

```css
body {margin: 0;}
canvas {background: #000;}
```

This works fine when the collision is on the y-axis, but collisions on the x-axis cause the player to "pop" out of the obstacle. Ordering the adjustments so that the least offending velocity adjustment is handled first should fix the problem. We do this by "undoing" the last move on one axis, checking if this single-axis move resolved the collision, and adjusting accordingly.

Putting it all together, here's a proof-of-concept:

```js
const canvas = document.createElement("canvas");
canvas.width = 300;
canvas.height = 180;
document.body.appendChild(canvas);
const ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
const mouse = {x: 0, y: 0};
const enemy = {x: 130, y: 70, width: 40, height: 40};
const player = {
  x: 0, y: 0, width: 20, height: 20, vx: 0, vy: 0, 
  velocityDamp: 0.06, collisionDamp: 0.3
};

const collides = (a, b) => 
  a.x + a.width >= b.x && a.x <= b.x + b.width &&
  a.y + a.height >= b.y && a.y <= b.y + b.height
;

const resolveOnAxis = (player, enemy, axis) => {
  while (collides(player, enemy)) {
    player[axis] -= Math.sign(player["v"+axis]) * player.collisionDamp;
  }
};

const resolveCollision = (player, enemy) => {
  player.x -= player.vx;

  if (collides(player, enemy)) {
    player.x += player.vx;
    resolveOnAxis(player, enemy, "y");
    resolveOnAxis(player, enemy, "x");
  }
  else {
    player.x += player.vx;
    resolveOnAxis(player, enemy, "x");
    resolveOnAxis(player, enemy, "y");
  }
};

(function render() {
  player.vx = (mouse.x - player.x) * player.velocityDamp;
  player.vy = (mouse.y - player.y) * player.velocityDamp;
  player.x += player.vx;
  player.y += player.vy;

  if (collides(player, enemy)) {
    resolveCollision(player, enemy);
  }  
  
  ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
  ctx.fillStyle = "blue";
  ctx.fillRect(enemy.x, enemy.y, enemy.width, enemy.height);
  ctx.fillStyle = "yellow";
  ctx.fillRect(player.x, player.y, player.width, player.height);  
  requestAnimationFrame(render);
})();

onmousemove = e => {
  mouse.x = e.clientX;
  mouse.y = e.clientY;
};
```

```css
body {margin: 0;}
canvas {background: #000;}
```

This isn't perfect collision resolution by any means, but it introduces a few fundamental concepts and should be sufficient for simple games.

Note that I'm only handling one enemy; it's left to the reader to create an array of enemies and loop over them to detect and resolve collisions. Problems can arise if multiple enemies are close together; resolving one collision could push the player into another collision. It gets worse if the obstacles are also moving. If you're making a platformer, a [collision grid](https://codepen.io/ggorlen/pen/ParbdN) might be worth looking into to circumvent some of these issues.

If dealing with collision becomes increasingly complicated and overwhelming, there's no shame in using a library like [matter.js](https://brm.io/matter-js/).

Be careful when using `while` to resolve these collisions as an infinite loop can easily occur. Consider adding a `tries` counter to these loops and bail if they exceed more than 20 or 30 iterations (this is a bit unsatisfactory and reveals that this solution is not industrial-strength; this prevents infinite loops but may result in incorrect behavior).

Capping the player's maximum velocity is another important preventative measure: it can avoid situations where the velocity becomes so high the player clips right through obstacles. Explore other ad-hoc solutions to problems as they arise.

Beyond collision detection, I have a few other suggestions:

- Use objects to encapsulate all properties associated with a game entity. This makes the code much easier to manage than loose variables like `playerwidth`, `playerheight`, `playerspeed`, etc.
- Avoid pointless and noisy comments that reiterate what the code clearly does.
- Instead of adding comments to delimit logical parts of a function, create helper functions with the appropriate names. My POC above is not great in this regard--as the game expands, objects, functions and overall design become increasingly important; inlining everything in the update loop makes for a painful coding experience as soon as you want to add features or run into bugs.
- Put `Enemy`'s constructor function outside of the game loop. Create enemies one time in an initialization function and scope constructors appropriately.
- Use `camelCased` variables instead of `everythinginlowercase`.