# Rectangle collision detection and stop player upon collision

Tags: javascript, html, html5-canvas, collision-detection, collision

You control a player on a 2d canvas, you can move around using 'WASD'. I want to create collision with another cube that's drawn on the screen (using `canvas.getContext('2d')`), and when you approach it from any side, it will stop the player from moving into that drawn cube (Collision).

I have the **X** and **Y** coordinate of the drawn cube, held in an array '[]', this array is called '`cubeX`' and the other is '`cubeY`'.

The player **X** and **Y** coordinate is held in a class, you can access this by using '`player.x`' or '`player.y`'

this is what i currently have, but it doesnt work even close to how i want it to

```
    cubeX.forEach(cubeX => {
    cubeY.forEach(cubeY => {
        // left
        if (player.x + player.w >= cubeX){
            if (player.x <= cubeX + cube.w){
                // stop when colliding with left of cube
            }
            // top
            if (player.y >= cubeY + cube.h){
                if (player.y + player.h <= cubeY){
                    // stop when colliding with bottom of cube
                }
            }

        // something similar to this
        } 
    });
});
```

**Please note that the collision code is being looped with '`requestAnimationFrame()`'**

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: What's the question? Please see [ask].

Comment: You can not handle both directions separately, as you are currently trying to do. Yes, my player might "collide" with your rectangle on the x axis - but what does that matter, if it is on such a high or low y coordinate, that it would simply pass above or below your box ...

Comment: The context isn't clear enough. Can the rectangle rotate? Do the entities have velocity? Please show a [mcve] and clarify exactly what behavior we need here, or take a look at many other rectangle-rectangle collision detection/resolution questions such as [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60252977/6243352), which uses the mouse but can be easily modified to keyboard.